# Node red floods syslog with [error] [function:check for lost changes] xx ERRORS

Tags: node-red

I have a node red flow, that while working floods the syslog with such messages:

```
Jul 10 06:31:07 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:07 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 35 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:08 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:08 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 149 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:09 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:09 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 142 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:10 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:10 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 140 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:11 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:11 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 143 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:12 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:12 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 143 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:13 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:13 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 148 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:14 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:14 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 1 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:15 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:15 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 233 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:16 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:16 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 151 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:17 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:17 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 130 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:18 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:18 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 144 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:19 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:19 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 139 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:20 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:20 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 127 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:21 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:21 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 125 ERRORS
Jul 10 06:31:22 NodeRedPi Node-RED[12267]: 10 Jul 06:31:22 - [error] [function:check for lost changes] 27 ERRORS
```

What could be the reason for that?

Interestingly, if the flow stops working, the messages no longer appear.

```
Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3B+
uname -a: Linux NodeRedPi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT   2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
Node Red Version: 0.20.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error being logged by a Function node with the name `check for lost changes`.

Within that node will be some code that includes a `node.error(...)` statement that is logging this message.

The fact you are asking this suggests you didn't write the Function node yourself.

Open up the flow editor, find this node (`Ctrl-F` to search for the name 'check for lost changes') and open its edit dialog. That will show you the code it contains. From there, you will have to figure out what the code is doing and what causes it to log this error.

Comment: Things can be so easy. Thank you.